# How can I empty the `dirs` stack, without changing my current directory?

Tags: bash, pushd

I have `pushd` several pathnames, so my `dirs` stack has multiple stack frames.

Now I would like to empty the stack, without changing my current directory. I wonder how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Read the man page, or `help dirs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `dirs` is a builtin, you can get help for it by running `help dirs`.

Doing so will inform you about the `-c` option, which clears your directory stack.

```
dirs -c
```

Answer (score 1):

For [bash](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_BUILTIN_COMMANDS):

```
dirs -c
```

---

```
$ pushd Devel/
~/Devel ~
$ dirs -c
$ dirs
~/Devel
$ pwd
/home/murphy/Devel
```